# Use Event Trigger to paste values from one range to a cell and another range and use the sum function to keep a running total [VBA]

Tags: excel, vba, loops, foreach, eventtrigger

I need to be able to create a loop (probably For Each) for the Column N and paste the sum of the values into cells C49, C50, C51 based on certain conditions. If Column G has a "No" value, then the value from Column N needs to only be pasted into C50, if it is a "Yes" value, then the value needs to go into C49. As you can see, C51 is a combination of both "Yes" and "No" values so I was able to accomplish that task. However, as you can see in C50, I am unable to get a sum of all "No" values as they are inputted, only the most recent cell value is taken. I need to be able to get the Sum of all "No" and "Yes" values and put them into C50 and C49 respectively. Additionally, I need to also be able to paste the timeline of this happening in D49:N49, D50:N50, D51:N51. By timeline I mean that based off of N3 being a "No" with a $1.00 value, that will go into D50 and the next "No" value is a $2.00 so that would go into E50 but also add onto the $1.00 value prior, so E50 would actually be a $3.00 amount. The first image I have attached is a visual of what I have so far, the second image is what the desired output is, as well as my code below. All help is appreciated, thank you.

*Edit-Added Jorge's code, all code being used is shown in the 3rd image, lmk if that is correct or not because I am not getting the desired result. For whatever reason, any "No" value is being inserted into B50 and C51 but not into B51 where it is supposed to go. Also, a running total is not being maintained. I only kept the declared variables (whatever is shown in the 3rd image) so maybe I messed up Jorge's anticipated result by not maintaining some of my code ...?

```
Private Sub test()

Dim wb_nyu_rap_calc As Workbook
Dim ws_loans As Worksheet
Dim rng_adj_monthly_payment As Range
Dim eligible_loan_payment As Long
Dim non_law_loan_payment As Long
Dim all_loan_payment As Long
Dim rng_law_debt As Range

Set wb_nyu_rap_calc = Workbooks("testnyu.xlsm")
Set ws_loans = wb_nyu_rap_calc.Sheets("Loans")
Set adj_monthly_payment = ws_loans.Range("N3:N22")
Set rng_law_debt = ws_loans.Range("G3:G22")

'All Loan Payment
ws_loans.Range("C51") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(adj_monthly_payment)

'Non Law Loan Payment
For Each cell In rng_law_debt
    If cell.Value = "No" And cell.Offset(0, 7).Value <> "" Then
        ws_loans.Range("C50") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cell.Offset(0, 7).Value)
        'ws_loans.Range("C50") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cell)
    End If
Next

'using this to test that the code is properly inputting
MsgBox ("DONE")

End Sub
*********************************************************
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N3:N22")) Is Nothing Then
Call test
End If
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is too much detail to sift through. Strip this down to the basic issue you're having where you have a set situation, some code, and the result you're getting, and the result that you want.

Comment: Also, paste your code into a code block instead of taking a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use variables to store the values of each sum.
I would change this:

```
'Non Law Loan Payment
For Each cell In rng_law_debt
    If cell.Value = "No" And cell.Offset(0, 7).Value <> "" Then
        ws_loans.Range("C50") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cell.Offset(0, 7).Value)
        'ws_loans.Range("C50") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cell)
    End If
Next
```

to this:

```
'Non Law Loan Payment
dim sumNo as double, sumYes as double
For Each cell In rng_law_debt
    If cell.Offset(0, 7).Value <> "" Then
        If cell.Value = "No" Then
            sumNo = sumNo + cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
        else if cell.value = "Yes" then
            sumYes = sumYes + cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
        End If
    End If
Next

ws_loans.Range("C49").value = sumYes
ws_loans.Range("C50").value = sumNo
```

The next part is a bit trickier, because you need to calculate the last used column on those 3 rows. Here's a function I use to get this:

```
Public Function lastCol(ByVal wSheet As Worksheet, x As Integer) As Long
    lastCol = wSheet.Cells(x, wSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End Function
```

Add it to your code, and then we can call it from inside the Ifs in the for loop to write every value to it's corresponding row (after writing a value first on the sum column, or we will miss the first value every time we run this), and also to the "All Loan Payment" row disregarding if cell is "Yes" or "No", like this:
(I added a cleanup of the sum cells, in order for this to work properly every time)

```
'Non, Eligible and All Law Loan Payment
dim sumNo as double, sumYes as double

'Cleanup
ws_loans.Range("C49:AA51").ClearContents
ws_loans.Range("C51") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(adj_monthly_payment)

For Each cell In rng_law_debt
    If cell.Offset(0, 7).Value <> "" then
        If cell.Value = "No" Then
            sumNo = sumNo + cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
            ws_loans.Range("C49").value = sumNo
            ws_loans.cells(50,lastcol(ws_loans,50)+1).value = cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
        else if cell.value = "Yes" then
            sumYes = sumYes + cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
            ws_loans.Range("C50").value = sumYes
            ws_loans.cells(49,lastcol(ws_loans,49)+1).value = cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
        End If
        ws_loans.cells(51,lastcol(ws_loans,51)+1).value = cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
    End If
Next
```

Please let me know if this works as you require, or if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi @Jorge, I edited my OP to show all of the code being used (3rd image) and I am thinking some of my previous code I was supposed to keep because the changes you provided isn't adding a running total, only grabbing the last inserted value. I appreciate your assistance, hopefully we can knock this problem out soon, I'll continue to mess around with what you have provided.

Comment: Hi @bgado I had an error in the code, I just realized. Could you please try again with the edited code?

Comment: Hi @Jorge, have you tried the code you provided with a test dataset? The first input of a "No" value is still populating where the field **Non Law Loan Debt** is (B50) and the code still isn't keeping a running total, only the most recent input. Maybe I'm not placing the code where it needs to be, which is why I provided the ss of the code that I am using based off your suggestions. However, I just went ahead and used a SUMIFS function in VBA and am getting the results I need. Not the approach I wanted to use but it works so that's all I can hope for at the moment. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I know what I missed. Sorry about that. Please try one last time.